# Adding extra data to widget output for Foreignkey fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

Say I have the following models...

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   specialty = models.CharField()

class Team(models.Model):
    captain = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    vice_captain = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

and I have a form for creating a team...

```
class TeamForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = Team
          widgets['vice_captain'] = MySelectWidget()
```

I also have an additional constraint for the form, whereby the Vice Captain must have the same Specialty as the Captain. I have implemented checks in the form clean etc, but want the UI to 'filter' itself. I have decided that rather than use ajax to populate/filter the field, I will add html 'data-' tags to the widget output, then hide options with javascript.

I have written a widget (and the javascript) that works with the an Select widget. Here it is (note this is simplified from my actual code, but should work).

```
class Select_with_Data(forms.Select):
    # Not sure if this is necessary.
    allow_multiple_selected = False

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):

        # This paragraph is copied from django Select.
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        if option_value in selected_choices:
            selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')
            if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
                # Only allow for a single selection.
                selected_choices.remove(option_value)
        else:
            selected_html = ''

        # My custom code to add data-specialty attributes to <option> tags.
        # Get the object to filter upon.
        obj = self.choices.queryset.get(pk=option_value)
        # Get the data field.
        data_field = getattr(obj, 'specialty', False)
        # If the data field has a value set, add it to the return html.
        # Need to check if the data_field has a pk (ie is a ForeignKey field), and handle it appropriately.
        if data_field:
            selected_html += ' data-{0}={1}'.format( 'specialty', str(getattr(data_field, 'pk', data_field)) )

        # This paragraph is copied from django Select.
        return format_html('<option value="{0}" {1}>{2}</option>',
                           option_value,
                           selected_html,
                           force_text(option_label))
```

But now I have decided I want radio buttons, not a select list. My problem is, attempting to use code similar to the above within the renderer of the radio widget fails, as self.choices.queryset isn't set, so I cannot access the information I need. **How can I get the information I need, and is this the best way to do what I want?**

I have even modified the core django files to see where the queryset was dissapearing. RadioSelect subclasses RendererMixin. self.choices.queryset is available during its *init*, render and get_renderer ?sub-functions? (is functions the word?). The renderer for RadioSelect is RadioFieldRenderer, which subclasses ChoiceFieldRenderer. Inside its *init* and render though, the queryset is gone (it sets its own self.choices, but even before that step in the *init*, self.choices isnt set).

Answer (score 4):

I discovered a few different methods to achieve what I wanted.

1: Write a custom widget that subclasses forms.Widget. This gives full control, no trying to 'work with' core classes. I used this link for inspiration, https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2589/

2: Modify the choices tuple, which is `(value,label)`, and changing it to `(value,label,object)` (for example). The following link gives the code to do so: http://srcmvn.com/blog/2013/01/15/django-advanced-model-choice-field/